# Exception Value: (1054, "Unknown column 'social_auth_usersocialauth.created' in 'field list'")

Tags: python-3.x, django, twitter

When trying to implement Django Social, I think i missed a migration somewhere and now when I get a twitter redirect to the site I get the following error.

```
Exception Value: (1054, "Unknown column 'social_auth_usersocialauth.created' in 'field list'")
```

I can see the table has been created, and two values aren't there in the database table:

```
    mysql> describe social_auth_usersocialauth;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| provider   | varchar(32)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| uid        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| extra_data | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id    | int          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.17 sec)
```

I want to run a custom migration to add the two fields that are missing from an update to the social auth migration,

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('dbdisplay', '0001_initial'),
    ('social_django', '0008_partial_timestamp'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='usersocialauth',
        name='created',
        field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=mytz.now),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='usersocialauth',
        name='modified',
        field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True),
    ),

]
```

But migrations don't understand the model I am referring to, because there is an error when I run the migration:

```
KeyError: ('social_django', 'association')
```

How to used AddField in a migration where the table is not in the app's namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is due to old version of python-social-auth (in that case social-core and social-app-django). The social_auth_usersocialauth table is missing the following fields:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
objects = UserSocialAuthManager()
```

Update your requirements.txt or pip install the latest versions.

```
social-auth-app-django==5.0.0
social-auth-core==4.1.0
```

Then

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And run the migrate command in django

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Afterwards check your DB table and then you will find the missing columns.

Comment: I have social-auth-core[all]==4.5.1 and social-auth-app-django==5.4.0 and i have this issue.

Comment: It's quiet a while ago i worked on that topic. Did you check your database schema and what does your Error exactly say?